# C: converting string array to float array OR read file with floats as floats not strings

Tags: arrays, c, types

I wan´t to read a file (10K float numbers each in a own row) and find the max_val element of it (I´m not that far now).
I managed to get the file into a char array but I need it to be a float array to be abled to find the max value.

Thanks for any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    char nameDatei[100];
    
    if(argv[1] != NULL) {
        strcpy(nameDatei, argv[1]);
    } else {
        printf("type in the name of the file: ");
        scanf("%s", nameDatei);
    }
    
    //read file;
    FILE *fPointer;
    fPointer = fopen("findMaxOfFloats.txt", "r");

    //save
    char singleLine[100];
    char content[10000][100];
    int i = 0;
   
    while (!feof(fPointer)){
        if (fgets(content[i], sizeof(singleLine), fPointer) != NULL)
            i++;    
    }

    fclose(fPointer);
    
    //print the array
    for(int loop = 0; loop < 10000; loop++){
    printf("%s", content[loop]);
    }
    

   //find max...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See [Why is `while(!feof(fp))` always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941). The correct way to write the loop is `while (fgets(singleLine, sizeof(singleLine), fPointer) != NULL)) { ... }`

Comment: And if the only goal is to find the maximum value, then you don't need an array. All that's needed is a `float` variable that stores the maximum seen so far. Read a line, extract the value using `sscanf` or `strtod`, then compare with the maximum, and update the maximum if needed.

Comment: Okay, thats a good idea. But if i want to do  it "my way". Do you have an idea how to make the input float or convert it to float?

Comment: This really isn't the right site to ask "how do I input a floating point value" or insist that you do it 'your way'. That is what the textbook is for. Implement what it says and if you have trouble, then ask here.

Comment: Why should I use floats and double instead? The code works now i used atof() to convert the strings. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Because `float` is inferior, and `double` is the natural type of the language, like `int` is for integers. `float` is 1980s and obsolete textbooks. You don't use `short` for small integers except when it is somehow necessary to save memory use. You can't even implement an accurate basic 8-digit calculator with `float`.

Comment: If you use `sscanf`, it will convert to `float` if you use the `%f` conversion specifier. If you use `strtod`, it will convert to `float` when you assign the returned value to a `float` variable. If by "your way", you mean you want to declare a million byte array `content` on the stack, and then fill it with the contents of the file, then good luck with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues ...

1. You read a line into `singleLine` but don't copy it into `content`
2. `feof` is bad--just check the `fgets` return value
3. You want `content` to be `double` and not just a `char` array.
4. After doing `fgets`, you can/should use `strtod` to convert the *string* in `singleLine` into a binary/floating point value.
5. You want to maintain a count of the number of lines read (i.e. the number of valid elements in `content`).
6. You get a filename from either `argv[1]` or `scanf` but then use a hardwired name instead.
7. You don't check the return value of `fopen`

Here is the refactored code. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXCONTENT      10000

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char nameDatei[100];

    if (argv[1] != NULL) {
        strcpy(nameDatei, argv[1]);
    }
    else {
        printf("type in the name of the file: ");
        scanf("%s", nameDatei);
    }

    // read file;
    FILE *fPointer;

// NOTE/BUG: You get a filename from either argv[1] or scanf but don't use it
#if 0
    fPointer = fopen("findMaxOfFloats.txt", "r");
#else
    fPointer = fopen(nameDatei, "r");
    if (fPointer == NULL) {
        perror(nameDatei);
        exit(1);
    }
#endif

    // save
    char singleLine[100];
#if 0
    char content[10000][100];
#else
    double content[MAXCONTENT];
#endif
#if 0
    int i = 0;
    while (!feof(fPointer)) {
        if (fgets(content[i], sizeof(singleLine), fPointer) != NULL)
            i++;
    }
#else
    int count = 0;

    // read in all lines until EOF
    while (fgets(singleLine,sizeof(singleLine),fPointer) != NULL) {
        // don't overflow the array
        if (count >= MAXCONTENT) {
            printf("count too large\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        // decode the number
        char *cp;
        content[count] = strtod(singleLine,&cp);

        // check for syntax error
        if (*cp != '\n') {
            printf("syntax error: %s",singleLine);
            exit(1);
        }

        ++count;
    }
#endif

    fclose(fPointer);

    // print the array
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < count;  ++idx)
        printf("%g\n", content[idx]);

    // find max... [and min, too ;-)]
    double max = content[0];
    double min = content[0];
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < count;  ++idx) {
        // get the current value
        double cur = content[idx];

        // set new maximum
        if (cur > max)
            max = cur;

        // set new minimum
        if (cur < min)
            min = cur;
    }

    printf("min=%g max=%g\n",min,max);

    return 0;
}
```

---

In the above code, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

Comment: Hello thank you a lot for your detailed explanation and correction of my code!! I managed to implement everything :) The inly remaining question is, why i shouldn´t use feof? Best regards Enno

Comment: I can´t vote, not enough reputation.